# Oracle Database Migration from 9i to 12c

Tags: database, oracle, migration, oracle12c, oracle9i

I am working in one use case where I have to migrate Oracle 9i Database to Oracle 12c, but as I am new in the Oracle database I wanted to know what sort of consequences might be there or what type of error I might get in the DB migration.

Also, Please suggest me if you have any tool or medium in this migration.

These are my requirements for the Client:

[image]

Comment: `What sort of consequences might be there or what type of error I might get in the DB migration.` The best answer is to do that on test database couple of time, because each environment with different data and objects can have different output.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in a single step. Most likely you have to run several upgrade, e.g. first to Oracle 10g -> 11g -> 12c. You should test the upgrade path very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should go for Oracle Database 19c it has the longest support. Oracle Database 12.2 goes out of support in November this year.

For such a small database it might be easiest to use the old import/export tool (imp/exp).

Otherwise, you need to do multiple upgrades:

- 9.2.0.1 => 9.2.0.8
- 9.2.0.8 => 11.2.0.4
- 11.2.0.4 => 19

Now, 11.2.0.4 is not supported on Windows XP, so you probably need to move to the 2012 server first.